# Trying to add buttons to my table view Navigation Bar

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to add a button to go back to a previous view controller. Since it is a table view Controller I have attempted to add a Navigation Controller hoping that I can put a button in there.

I have also tried doing it programmatically:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))

    fetchUser()
}
@objc func handleCancel(){
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here is a picture of me attempting to set the navigation bar
[link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED2iL.png)
I am not able to see the navigation item or the bar or anything. it is just the table showing up. anyone Knows how to actually get it to work?

Comment: Where's your attempt to put the view controller in a navigation controller? Sounds like you haven't set that up.

Comment: Just edited it and added a picture

Comment: That image does not show your view controller being in a navigation controller.

Comment: Can I only have a top bar if it is embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: I just want a "back" button. The only thing I want is to go back to my previous view controller

Comment: Then put the first vc in a navigation controller. When needed push the table view controller onto that navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late but: 
go to Main.storyboard -> in the top bar go to editor -> embed in -> navigation controller. do that to your viewController and than when u go to any other viewController from that ViewController you will be having that back button